# Different index of refraction for different prism

Tags: optics, refraction

I would like to just know more why different prisms have different index of refraction? From the point of view of atomic physics or something?

I do not seek for full proof and derivation (which is also fine), but would like to know more conceptual approach?

I know it is from the point there is an interaction of light and matter, but no idea what else to continue or how to think about this.

Comment: Different types of glass have different optical constants. Is that what you mean by different prisms? Two different prisms made of the same glass will have the same optical constants.

Comment: Indeed. Glass with lead or other heavy elements will have a larger refraction index because large ions are more polarizable.